# C# - Image question

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, image, computer-vision

What would be the appropriate way to determine if 2 taken images match in the color gamma terms?

*I need to differ the images taken in one series (panorama-like) from completely other images.*

This somehow correlates with color-distinct features of `Google` when doing image search, could someone suggest any approach?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest looking at color histograms, and matching those. There are many computer vision approaches to this problem.

Comment: please phrase the question subject line better. Your pattern is something like "C# Foo question", which does nothing to draw anybody's attention.

Comment: In particular, don't include `C#` in the title.  That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution. You may try to calculate HSV [color histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram) of images and then compare query's histogram to all images histogram to find best match using some of comparing methods (some methods are listed [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/histograms.html#cv-comparehist)).

However In your case it seems that [CLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Layout_Descriptor) is more suitable since it takes into account spacial features of image.